# Is there a real time wifi traffic analyzer for Android?

Tags: wi-fi

I'm using [SugarSync](http://www.sugarsync.com/en) to sync files between my phone and my computer, but I'm not sure if things are actually working as they should.
It would be great to watch Android network traffic in real time.

Does anyone know of an app?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an app called [3G WatchDog](https://market.android.com/details?id=net.rgruet.android.g3watchdog).
It can monitor 3G data transfer and Wi-Fi traffic. A pretty neat application.

[image: Real Time Wifi Traffic Display]

<sub>Click image for larger version</sub>

Answer (score 6):

Isn't really an answer, but...

There is [WiFi Analyzer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.farproc.wifi.analyzer) which shows more information on the wireless networks your device can reach. It gives you more detail than the average user would require.

As far as I know, there is no application available on Android (yet?) that can *"sniff packets"*.

Would be an interesting application to have in the pocket.

Comment: Cool app.  Thanks for pointing it out.  I use Tomato firmware on my router to do the same thing but Wifi Analyzer will make it much easier.

Comment: This isnt true now. If you have root access. There are a variety of Packet sniffing applications and some which even do session and cookie hijacking for you. Facesniff and Droidsheep are 2 prime examples.

Answer (score 3):

You can view, sniff, and save actual network packets, however this requires root access.

[Shark for Root](https://market.android.com/details?id=lv.n3o.shark) app does this.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need root to do this! Android apps can utilize the [VpnService API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/VpnService.html) to capture packets without root.

Here are some apps I found that do not require root:

- [Packet Capture](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=app.greyshirts.sslcapture)
- [tPacketCapture](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.co.taosoftware.android.packetcapture)

Answer (score 0):

[Internet Speed Meter Lite](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.internet.speed.meter.lite) is an app which exactly does it.

Answer (score 0):

I use [CoolTool](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ds.cpuoverlay) to get current information about my phone. And with this you can monitor traffic data (ascending and descending).

The pro is that it displays as an overlay then you can monitor while using the app. Hope this will be helpful.

Answer (score -1):

[Network Log](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.googlecode.networklog) is an app quite simple to use. It shows real time packets in a human-readable way as well as statistics. It takes it directly from iptables, hence you need a rooted device.